# Should applicationIconBadgeNumber be reset to number of unread notifications?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm having doubt regarding when and how the `applicationIconBadgeNumber` should be reset, if the app has multiple features that can get push notification, say if user gets 5 push notifications, among them there are 2 for feature A and 3 for feature B, if user opens the app and reads the new messages for feature A, should I reset `applicationIconBadgeNumber` to 3 or 0? I've seen commonly people reset it to 0 when the app launches, is this a common convention, and does Apple have any guideline on this?

Thanks!

Comment: there is no common convention and from your example the most logical thing to do is to decrease the badge number from 5 to 3 instead of 0. however this doesn't make sense on a chat app where even if you got `n` new messages, the moment you open that chat all are marked as read so the badge should be reset to 0 (considering you only have one chat room)